# How to update something in the database whenever the user clicks browser's back button / refresh button / close button?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

So, when a user does any of those 3 events, I want to update something in the MongoDB. I've searched here on the stack overflow and got some information which tells me to use $stateChangeStart. So, I've written the following lines after my app.config has ended:

```
.run(['$state', '$cookies', '$rootScope', function($state, $cookies, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log('e', e);
        console.log('toState', toState);
        console.log('toParams', toParams);
        console.log('fromState', fromState);
        console.log('fromParams', fromParams);
    });
}]);
```

The problem is, the browser is going only up to $rootScope.$on. After that, the console.log lines aren't executed. I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to solve this problem. After this, I was thinking to solve my issue of changing something in the DB in the following way:

1 - I will add some properties to the state like stateNumber or whatever.

2 - Then using that property, there will be if(toState.stateNumber == 1)

3 - Then depending upon toState.stateNumber being 1 or 2 or whatever, I'll update the database

Any thoughts are appreciated on how to solve these.

Comment: Have you tried $locationChangeSuccess instead of $stateChangeStart?

Comment: @pedrumgolriz Yes, Sir! I am trying it right now. It is not raising any errors. But when I do console.log($location.path()), nothing is logged, while console.log($rootScope.actualLocation) logs undefined.Why is that?

Comment: I believe its because its in .run, try sticking it directly in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in my application:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
});

$rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
    if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
            //post to mongo
    }
});
```